# extjs4 data.store use with proxy

Tags: ajax, yii, extjs4

I want to get data from Yii controller action in Ext.data.store with following code:

```
var vehicles = new Ext.data.Store({
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            fields: ['vehiclename'],
            root: 'vehicles'
        }),
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url: '<?php echo $this->createUrl('GetVehicles');?>'
        }),
        autoLoad: true
    });
```

or following code for vehicles:

```
var vehicles = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: [
            {name: 'vehiclename'}
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '<?php echo  $this->createUrl('GetVehicles'); ?>',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root:'vehicles'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    });
```

My action code is:

```
public function actionGetVehicles()
{
    $sql = "select vehicleName from vehicletbl inner join companytbl on vehicletbl.companyid=companytbl.companyid and companytbl.companyid='2';";
    $vehicles = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
    //var_dump($vehicles);
    echo '{vehicles:'.json_encode($vehicles).'}';
}
```

When i send request to action with browser address bar i get following json:

```
{vehicles:[{"vehiclename":"pride"},{"vehiclename":"benz"}]}
```

but i don't know why Ext.data.store can't get data and store themes!
What is wrong in my code?
I use store at:

```
items: [treePanel,Ext.create('Ext.grid.PropertyGrid', {
                            title: 'History',
                            closable: false,
                            header: true,
                            sortableColumns: false,
                            customEditors: {
                                Vehicle: Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {                       
                                    store: vehicles,
                                    queryMode: 'local',
                                    displayField: 'vehiclename'

                                })
                            },
                            /*propertyNames: {
                                'evtStart': 'Start Time'
                            },*/
                            source: {
                                "Vehicle": 'Select Vehicle',
                                "Select Start Date": false,
                                "Select End Date": true
                            }
                        })]
```

Chrome developer tool output:
[image]

Comment: I use `displayField: 'name'` in my ComboBox and data doesn't showed and i changed it to `displayField: 'vehiclename'` and every things ok!

Answer (score 1):

You returned json is not valid. It should be:

```
{"vehicles":[{"vehiclename":"pride"},{"vehiclename":"benz"}]}
```

(Quotation marks around the root `vehicles`).

Comment: I edit my action code and use `echo '{"vehicles":'.json_encode($vehicles).'}';` and get your recommended json but it doesn't work!

Comment: Try moving the `fields` config from the reader to the store (reader doesn't have `fields` config, store does).

Comment: When i use chrome developer tool i see that var vehicles length is 0 and hasn't any data in it!.How can i see in developer tool that store can send request to action or no?

Comment: I edited my question and i used other code for my vehicles variable but doesn't work!

Comment: `var vehicles` is your store, why should it have any length? And when are you testing for `vehicles`? Are you listening to the store's load event somewhere?

Comment: I edited my question with developer tool output and where i am using store.No i not listening any where!

Comment: Well, when you reach this line, the store is not even created it. Once you create it, an async load will happen (meaning that a server request is made, but the javascript execution continue). When the server respond (which could be after 15 seconds if the server is really slow) you get a load event from the store. You'd need to listen to this store event, once you catch it, your store should be loaded.

Comment: One of the comment on the [Ext.data.Store docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-listeners) shows you how to listen to the load event.

Comment: And I take it you can see in Developer Tools the XHR and a correct response, right?

Comment: When i use XHR tab in Network Developer tools i can't see any request or response!

Comment: For the sake of experiment try `url: 'test'`

Comment: I use this code at localhost and i don't know why server is slow!.How can i add store to the combobox after it loaded?

Comment: Ok i can see request to action and json data in it but how can i set themes to combobox?